# A question on a ballet dancer and her moment of inertia?

Tags: angular-momentum, rotational-dynamics, conservation-laws, moment-of-inertia

The classical example of conservation of angular momentum. I want to ask how we know that moment of inertia around center of mass change when in same time also center of mass change position? Why final moment of inertia is less than the initial?

Comment: Could you say specifically what example you are thinking of, and why you think in that situation the center of mass changes position?

Comment: https://www.google.gr/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj3taXK1MreAhWO_qQKHYqvCBEQjRx6BAgBEAU&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.skhlkmss.edu.hk%2Fphysics%2Frotational%2520dynamics%2Fangmomentum.htm&psig=AOvVaw0Loi_rkdnutidDu5euNeWE&ust=1541967883237777

Comment: we change the position of mass therefore center of mass must change and go to right or left or up and down

Comment: If you change the position of mass symmetrically, e.g. by extending your arms to either side in the same way, the center of mass would stay the same.